# How to write this series as a ratio of polynomials?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I have the series:

$g(z) = \sum^{\infty}_{0} b_{n}z^{n}$ where $z\in$$\mathbb{C}$.

$b_{n}$ is the $n^{th}$ number in the sequence, i.e. $(b_{0},b_{1},b_{2},b_{3},...)$ = (1,1,2,3,...)

How can I write this expression as a ratio of polynomials?

I don't really understand what I am even being asked or why.

I've tried rewriting  as:

$g(z) = 1 + z + 2z^{2} + ... + (a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})z^{n} + ...$

I could try writing out z in expanded form $x+iy$ and observing what happens with alternate powers, but I do not see how that gets me closer to a polynomial form.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 2):

$g(z) - zg(z) = \sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty b_nz^n - \sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty b_nz^{n+1}\\
g(z)(1 - z) = \sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty b_nz^n - \sum_\limits{n=2}^\infty b_{n-1}z^{n} \\
g(z)(1 - z) = b_1z + \sum_\limits{n=2}^\infty (b_n-b_{n-1})z^n$

By the definition of the Fibonacci sequence.

$b_{n} = b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}\\
b_{n} - b_{n-1} = b_{n-2}$

$g(z)(1 - z) = z + \sum_\limits{n=2}^\infty b_{n-2}z^n\\
g(z)(1 - z) = z + z^2 g(z)\\
g(z) = \frac {z}{1-z-z^2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$g(z) = \sum^{\infty}_{0} F_{n}z^{n}=\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}$$